# Did the US push the Kurds to lower their defences against Turkey in the months preceding the latest Turkish military operation against them?

Tags: united-states, military, turkey, kurds

CNN [reports](https://edition.cnn.com/2019/10/09/politics/turkey-syria-us-anger-ramifications/index.html):

> Analysts such as Bowman say part of the outrage is driven by the fact that "we would have not defeated ISIS' Caliphate ... without their help" and that the Kurds had just recently lowered their defenses, trusting the US to protect them from Turkey.
>
> **Since August, the US has been pushing the Kurds to dismantle their defensive fortifications and pull back their troops along the border that Turkey is now attacking as part of a "security mechanism" framework. The goal was to appease Turkey enough so they wouldn't invade. Kurds agreed to participate "presumably because they trusted the US to restrain the Turks diplomatically," Bowman said.**

Note that CNN attributes this versions of events to an analyst, so CNN doesn't fully put their own editorial weight behind the (attributed) statement. So what evidence exists that lends credence to this claim?

Comment: You mean the [Northern Syria Buffer Zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northern_Syria_Buffer_Zone)? "The DMZ was managed by United States Armed Forces and Turkish Armed Forces personnel until the agreement was abandoned and in early October 2019..." -- "On 27 August, the first stage of the planned Kurdish withdrawal came into effect, with YPG units leaving their positions and withdrawing along with their weapons from Tell Abyad and Ras al-Ayn." -- Is there anything this WP article *doesn't* answer?

Comment: @DevSolar: it's not clear from there that US pushed for the dismantling, as opposed to the Turkish side. After all the (failed) buffer zone deal was a 3-way thing.

Comment: Have you *read* the article? The negotiations were mainly between Turkey and the USA, with the *USA* promising a retreat of the SDF so there could be a Turkish-US patrolled DMZ. I don't see how this could happen *without* the US telling the Kurds to vacate the area. At the very least, your question would require some sharpening of what you're skeptical about, precisely.

Comment: @Fizz How clear do you need?  Turkey refuses to negotiate with the Kurds, so the US carried out talks with Turkey on behalf of their Kurdish allies, and the Kurds agreed to cooperate with their US allies.  (Allies at the time, anyway; most likely bitter enemies now.)  It's also important to mention that a direct quote does not mean the outlet "doesn't fully put their own editorial weight behind the statement", merely that they have a direct quote for something which is correct beyond any possible challenge.

Answer (score 32):

The best I could confirm from official sources is this US CENTCOM [tweet](https://twitter.com/CENTCOM/status/1164981779708698624):

> Within 24 hours of the phone call between U.S. SECDEF and Turkish MINDEF to discuss security in northeast Syria, the SDF destroyed military fortifications, Aug 22. This demonstrates SDF's commitment to support implementation of the security mechanism framework.

Comment: I wasn't aware that they had any fortifications at the Louisville KY airport.

Comment: @DanielRHicks: I'm missing the joke somehow. (Ah, I see, IATA code SDF.) The obviously mean [that SDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syrian_Democratic_Forces).

Comment: @DanielRHicks Someone has to keep UPS safe.

Answer (score 23):

See this [article](https://thedefensepost.com/2019/08/27/ypg-syria-turkey-border-withdrawal-begins/) which includes pictures of the removal of fortifications.

[image]

photo caption reads:

> A US service member observes as Syrian Democratic Forces remove military fortifications along the Turkey-Syria border, August 22, 2019. Image: US Army/Spc. Alec Dionne

Comment: [Your answer is in another castle](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer). Please [edit] the essentials into your text.

Answer (score 13):

See [Turkey, US agree to set up operation centre for Syria safe zone](https://www.aljazeera.com/news/2019/08/turkey-agree-set-syria-safe-zone-operation-centre-190807140235933.html) 7 August 2019:

> A joint statement by the Turkish defence ministry and the US embassy in Ankara said the two sides had agreed to set up the Turkey-based operations centre "as soon as possible" and that the safe zone "would become a "peace corridor", without providing futher details.

More-officially, see [Statement on Joint Military Talks Regarding Syria](https://tr.usembassy.gov/statement-on-joint-military-talks-regarding-syria/)

See also the follow-up article [Syrian Kurdish fighters 'start pulling back' from Turkish border](https://www.aljazeera.com/news/2019/08/syrian-kurdish-fighters-start-pulling-turkish-border-190827133422573.html) 27 August 2019:

> the SDF said they were withdrawing as much as 17km into the Syrian territory.

Comment: "safe zone"... hmmm...

Comment: @sfmiller940: Hey, it's safe for Turkey...